# This code can't find first element

Tags: python, list, function

```
def c(stringenter):
    last = 1
    commandsline = [['a', 'first'], ['b', 'second'], ['c', 'third']]
    for commandblock in commandsline:
        last = last + 1
        if commandblock[0] == stringenter:
            realcommand = str(commandblock[1])
        elif last == len(commandsline):
            realcommand = stringenter
    return realcommand
```

Hello!!! This code can find and return second, third but can't find first how  resolve problem?

Comment: I think you have to change `last = 1` to `last = 0`.

Comment: You've tagged both [python-2.7] and [python-3.x] -- these tags generally mean "I only target this version specifically" and for generic python questions should generally not be used

Comment: @AnthonySottile totally right, very good observ.

Comment: two things, start index with 0, and update index at the end of using it!

Comment: Hman don't forget accept one answer with the simbol (✓) top left the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

indices starts in 0, so you must change like this, another think, you should update the counter at the end!:

```
def c(stringenter):
    last = 0
    commandsline = [['a', 'first'], ['b', 'second'], ['c', 'third']]
    for commandblock in commandsline:
        if commandblock[0] == stringenter:
            realcommand = str(commandblock[1])
        elif last == len(commandsline):
            realcommand = stringenter
        last = last + 1
    return realcommand
```

Answer (score 3):

While @Damian's answer correctly answers your question, you may find the two other forms of your function easier:

```
def c(stringenter):
    commandsline = [['a', 'first'], ['b', 'second'], ['c', 'third']]
    for key, cmd in commandsline:
        if stringenter == key:
            return cmd
    return stringenter
```

Or just use a dictionary directly:

```
def c(stringenter):
    commandsline = {'a': 'first', 'b': 'second', 'c': 'third'}
    return commandsline.get(stringenter, stringenter)
```

Comment: Just an example of a perfect answer I must say, plus one for experience and good practice advices

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
def c(stringenter):
    commandsline = [['a', 'first'], ['b', 'second'], ['c', 'third']]
    for commandblock in commandsline:
        if commandblock[0] == stringenter:
            return commandblock[1]
    return stringenter
```

It goes through your commandsline list if stringenter is equal to any of the ones in commandblock[0] it returns commandblock[1]

If it doesnt find it. It returns stringenter.

Comment: That's just correct! fantastic, but! careful, because if you call the function with a value that is not there, the function returs to you the same value, and that's a little awful :( it's better to raise an error than return something if the function doesn't do the expected. But is right, plus one

Comment: Thank you this is working and more readable for me. Program will take returned code to terminal and there is not problem if terminal do one more enter but is it bad programming style even  if program will work correct?

Comment: Yes it is bad programming style. It is better to raise exceptions if something isnt going the way it should.

Exceptions are messages a function can send to the function that called it. If you write function O and inside you call function T and there is an error, you can raise Exception in function T, then function T will tell function O that it didn't finish because there was an Exception.

If you raise an Exception, the function stops working at the line you raise the Exception.

Exceptions are there to protect our programs.